# Programatically request recent close prices for a list of stock tickers

Tags: data-request, real-time

I have a list of stock tickers and for each ticker I need today's close price and yesterday's close price.

I could use (have used) Yahoo Historical Data API by sending `GET` requests of the following form:
`http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?params-go-here`
But I have to make a separate data request for each ticker. For large lists of tickers this approach is very network intensive, very slow, and very prone to communication errors.

Is there a data source API which I could send a list of tickers (in any format) and receive a list of today's close price & yesterday's close price for each ticker sent?

(A single 1D array in the request and a single 2D array in the response.)

---

**EDIT :**

This question was intended as an API referral, not an example code request.

Comment: This is a programming question and belongs on StackOverflow.

Comment: did you read through http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/, anyway I agree it's not a data-request and doesn't belong here

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO  I personally view this as 'I have a source of data that's a real pain to use, is there some API available that's designed for my intended use?', and so programming only comes into play if that can't be answered.

Comment: @Joe, agreed - I almost posted the same comment after reading this question. I think it certainly has one foot in Open Data (recommendation for a suitable API) and one in Stack Overflow (how to request specific data). It's important for the question to be left open (perhaps rephrased) so that we can elicit answers with relevant information such as the one given by FreshPrinceOfSO.

Answer (score 4):

While the [Google Finance API](https://developers.google.com/finance/) is *officially* no longer available,  it's still active in returning requests in XML.

```
// Dow Jones
http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=.DJI

// NASDAQ
http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=IXIC
```

You will need to consult a programming site like [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com)  if you have a programming related question.

Comment: No longer works :/